# "command 'gcc' failed" when trying to install a Python package from pypi

Tags: python, programming, gcc

I'm trying to install 'pyskein' from the Python package index (`sudo easy_install3 skein`), but the installation fails with this error:

```
src/threefish.c:23:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've already installed the `build-essential` package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your system is missing the Python headers. To fix this, run

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```